# GAE Session id mismatch

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I am running into an issue with GAE and session management.

I have an endpoint that creates and stores user information in a session upon successful login.

However, I am unable to retrieve the information back on the client side. One thing I've noticed is for jsessionid and gae session id being different.

Session is being created in google's datastore but like I said, the id differs from the one on the client side (jsessionid).

I have tested using servlet instead of endpoints and everything works like a charm... So what I did in order to pinpoint the root cause is to downsize my code to a very basic example (see below).

Any idea what the root cause is? Appreciate your help. Thanks.

**GAE Endpoint**

```
@ApiMethod(name = Path.OperationUrl.TEST, path = Path.OperationUrl.TEST, httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public Response test(HttpServletRequest request) throws DatabaseException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");

    //creating a session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("name", name);
    session.setAttribute("pwd", pwd);
    session.setAttribute("sessionId", session.getId());


    return new Response(STATUS.SUCCESS, "Session was created...." + session.getId());
}
```

**JSP Page**

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<button type="submit" onclick="callEndpoint();">Click</button>

<p>username: ${name}</p/><br>
<p>pwd: ${pwd}</p>

<script>
function callEndpoint(){
    gapi.client.userEndpoint.test().execute(function(resp) {
        if(resp.status === 'SUCCESS'){
            alert(resp.message);
        }else{
            alert(resp.message);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<script>
function init() {
    var location = window.location.origin;
    gapi.client.load('userEndpoint', 'v1', null, location+'/_ah/api');
}
</script>
<script src="//apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the root problem is that endpoints aren't actually handled by your app directly. They go through Google's architecture first that's why you are probably getting inconsistent JsessionIds as Servlet request are being dispatched by you but endpoint request are actually coming form somewhere else.

What we use for endpoints is to return a "token" as the result of a successful login, we then send that token (header) on every request from the client side and fetch session based on that token. We are using objectify's @Cache to aggressively cache sessions as their info is no changed often, we just use this for authorization and authentication purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with appengine custom domain.
This happens becouse servlet end endpoint domain mistmatch.
For servlet the domain is "www.myapp.com", for endpoint "myapp".appspot.com